# Add Cancel button to default camera on Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am currently using the default camera to take photos for my app.

It currently displays Retry and OK buttons at the top of the screen when launched, is there any way of adding cancel to this, which would return the user to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Since we launch the default camera app with startActivityForResult(), which means you are kind of moving out of the app and seeking Result on completion of task on the CameraIntent. Customizing Camera intent is in not your hand untill Camera app exposes some API to do so(which is not yet available).